# Why do I see some random transactions to "The DAO" in my mist client?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, mist, the-dao, internal-transactions

I am curious to know, why I do see some random transactions of "The DAO" in my mist client within my "last transactions" section. I have actually two of them yet:

[image: last transactions in mist client]

Is it because I watch my Tokens?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known UI issue in Mist. It's nothing to be concerned about and just is something that occasionally happens when you are watching The DAO contract / tokens.

From my personal experience, it sometimes stems from users sending tokens or ETH to The DAO address itself. Since you are watching this contract, it will show up in your recent transactions as Mist shows you both incoming and outgoing transactions from your contracts.

There have been times where it just seems to be a glitch that displays transactions that do not concern you for no particular discernible reason.

Regardless, it is nothing to be worried about.